# constrainging database with alternate foreign keys

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I have a database table that I am using as an interface between systems. I write to it, they read from it. I have a foreign key in the table that references my user table.

Now the interface is getting more complex. I now have another use for the interface table that doesn't reference the user table. I can of course relax the foreign key constraint to user table.

What I want to do is have a constraint state either this foreign key is satisfied OR this other key (in different column) is satisfied. Is this possible?

I have an oracle database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a different table for the new interface requirements.  One difference in constraints just leads to another.

Then I'd think about whether I should create a view, and let the application software read from the view instead of from the base table(s).

Comment: Creating the view was the best option

Answer (score 3):

You can declare both columns to be nullable and create a check constraint that ensures that exactly one of the two columns is not NULL.

For example, if I have separate tables for professors and for lecturers and I wanted to model classes such that a class can either have a professor or a lecturer but not both, I can do something like this

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create table professor(
  2    professor_id number primary key
  3* )
SQL> /

Table created.

SQL> create table lecturer(
  2    lecturer_id number primary key
  3  );

Table created.

SQL> create table class(
  2    class_id number primary key,
  3    lecturer_id number references lecturer( lecturer_id ),
  4    professor_id number references professor( professor_id ),
  5    check( (lecturer_id is null and professor_id is not null) or
  6           (lecturer_id is not null and professor_id is null) )
  7  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into professor values( 1 );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into lecturer values( 20 );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into class values( 1, 20, null );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into class values( 2, null, 1 );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into class values( 3, 20, 1 );
insert into class values( 3, 20, 1 )
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.SYS_C0014175) violated
```

Of course, from a data modeling standpoint, it will frequently be a better idea to create a single `INSTRUCTOR` table with an `INSTRUCTOR_TYPE` that can be either `LECTURER` or `PROFESSOR` and to create the `CLASS` table with a non-nullable foreign key to the `INSTRUCTOR` table.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible. You *can* put together what would amount to a tertiary key table that links out to either one or the other tables, but it is *very* messy and brittle.

Instead, I would *highly* suggest you revisit your integration strategy, since it seems that your current one isn't able to flex the way you need it to.

Comment: I agree that it is a kludge. But is it more of a kludge than having two tables exposed?